# CrossWalk WebRTC not working with apache cordova

Tags: apache, cordova, webrtc

I'm starting with WebRTC , cord apache and ionic and Crosswalk . I'm trying to follow the crosswalk tutorial on WebRTC in https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/webrtc.html . I did all what is there and compiled my app with Apache cord using the cord build command. But it seems that is not working , as opposed to show the vision of my camera is a black square. What it is that? Could someone help me ?

Comment: stream from intel xdk emulator using peerjs is displaying on mobile, but not vice versa.it coulld be a memory issue on mobile device